# how to hover over text using css

Tags: css

I want to use the hover  in css to increase the size of text in a heading tag, however every time they are hovered over, the size increases.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;,
    h1:hover {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 30px;
    }">This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Questions should be proper

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m4k90bso/

Comment: you are looking for a normal hover style or you need to increment the font size on each hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow. Hover should be done through CSS. Below is the code you can use.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1:hover { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; font-size: 30px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">This is a heading</h1> 
<p>This is a paragraph.</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

One thing to note is using this will mean all h1's will be affected with this code. If you want to target a single H1 then I would use a class on the html and reference that in the CSS.

How this is what you were after.

Comment: i just want to increase the font size on hover without changing the position how can i implement this??

Answer (score 0):

> you can not use `:hover` in `inline style`.you can use it in `External style sheet` OR `Internal style sheet`.

```css
h1:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">This is a heading</h1> 
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't implement hover effects using inline CSS. You have to use External Style sheets or normal script tags. Your code will look like this:
**Style.css:**

```
h1:hover { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; font-size: 30px; }
```

**index.html:**

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>

        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

        </body>
        </html>
```